# Multiple Objects into HttpParams

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I have some categories in a formcontrol, I send them in an array of string like this:

> [1,4,6]

And that is my actual code:

```
let categoryIds = new Array<String>()
this.selectedCategories.forEach((value: string, key: string) =>
  categoryIds.push(key))

let requestOptions = {
    params: new HttpParams()
        .set('title', this.createNewForm.controls['title'].value)
        .append('content', this.createNewForm.controls['content'].value)
        .append('categoryids', categoryIds.toString()),              
    withCredentials: true
}
```

But I want to send them as an array of objects, with the old version of angular Http I was able to do a foreach of the object and append every category.
But I don't know how to get every category and make each one an append to params.
I need to get like this:

> ...categoryId=1&categoryId=4&categoryId=6...

Comment: little not clear about your q?.. If you want to send it as objects you can set using angular common HttpClient or http but not as params

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `.append` to append values to a parameter and give you the result you are looking for when dealing with an array of values. `.set` is used to set or replace a value for a parameter. So really you should be doing something more like the following:

```
let httpParams = new HttpParams()
  .set('title', this.createNewForm.controls['title'].value)
  .set('content', this.createNewForm.controls['content'].value);

categoryIds.forEach(id => {
  httpParams = httpParams.append('categoryId', id);
});

const requestOptions = {
  params: httpParams,
  withCredentials: true
};
```

---

It's not obvious, but the `.append` method does not mutate the `HttpParams` object it was called from but instead returns a new object. This is why we reassign `httpParams` in the example above. Also, `.append` can be called without first using `.set` to set the parameter.

Comment: The fact that we need to use an `append` method instead of a `set` method was surprising to me. Add to this, that we also need to reassign the object to itself was even more so.

Comment: @Stephane I agree that it's confusing at first glance. I updated my answer with a little more detail.

Comment: @RichMcCluskey sorry for asking a question in comment box because i am ban to ask question on this plateform. my problem is related to this answer so please take a look here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-66qunm

Answer (score 15):

You can create object containing all parameters and pass this object to `fromObject` property of `HttpParamOptons` while creating `HttpParams`

```
let data={
   firstname:'xyz',
   lastname:'pqr'
}

let body=new HttpParams({fromObject:data})

this.http.post(URL, body, this.header).subscribe(data => {
 ....
}, error => {
 ....
})
```

Comment: your answer has saved me tons of codding.

Answer (score 1):

May be this is what you are looking for

**component file:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

data = [
       {id:'_', title:'_', content:'_'},
       ....,
       ....
       ];

mainArr:any = [];

constructor(){}

getCategory(item){
    this.mainArr.push({title:item.title,content:item.content,categoryId:item.id});

   console.log('mainArr',this.mainArr);

   let requestOptions = {
        params: new HttpParams()
        .append('data', this.mainArr),
        withCredentials: true
    }

   console.log('requestOptions',requestOptions);
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I am sending like this "...categoryId=[1,2]", but on api side I need to get like this "...categoryId=1&categoryId=2..." How can I do that?