# How to iterate over object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an object like this:

```
  const params = {
     'userId[]': [1, 2],
     'empId': 2,
     advance: 'hello',
     };
```

and I want to make a string like this:

```
userId[]=1&userId[]=2&empId=2&advance=hello
```

I am trying like this:

```
 const myResult = Object.entries(params)
 .map(([key, value]) => {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    let result;
    value.forEach(item => {
    `${key}=${value}`
    })
    return result
  }
 // return 
 })
 .join('&');

 console.log(myResult);
```

but not able to figure out what to do next.

Comment: Your params have empId = 2, but your desired string has empId = 5? Is this a typo?

Comment: @caTS yah it was typo error. sorry

Comment: Related question: [Query-string encoding of a Javascript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/query-string-encoding-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47164688/4826457 angular uses `HttpParams` object to build the URL params

Comment: @SurajRao but in google chrome,when there is any special charachter in query params, it automatically gets encoded, to avoid that I am trying to do in string format

Comment: Seems like reinventing the wheel since Angular already has methods for doing this and that can serialize arrays in the format it expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a few changes, adding concatenation and non-array values:

```js
const params = {
  "userId[]": [1, 2],
  empId: 2,
  advance: "hello",
}

const myResult = Object.entries(params)
  .map(([key, value]) => {
    // Assume non-array result as default
    let result = `${key}=${value}`

    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      // Override for arrays
      const r = value
        .map((item) => {
          return `${key}=${item}`
        })
        .join("&")

      result = r
    }

    return result
  })
  .join("&")

console.log(myResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

[URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) can do most of the work for us, but we still have to handle the array ourselves:

```js
const params = {
  'userId[]': [1, 2],
  'empId': 2,
  advance: 'hello',
};

const p = new URLSearchParams();

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(params)) {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        for (const item of value) {
            p.append(key, item);
        }
    } else p.append(key, value);
}

console.log(p.toString());
```

Looping through the entries of our object, we check if the value is an array. If it isn't we append it, otherwise, we append all its items. URLSearchParams makes the string for us; all we do is tell it what to use for the string :)

*Note: "%5b%5D" is the same as "[]" but it's URI encoded. It should be treated the same by the server.*

Comment: I need it in string format only. because while I am making api call it will get encoded. to avoid that I am doing all these things, i mean I want it in string only

Comment: @techguy Why? It will get URI encoded anyways.

Comment: no, if we are making it string and appending it to url directly, then it is working fine, I tried it. I am using Angular framework

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following instead of iterating over the object:
`url = Object.keys(params).map(function(k) {return k + '=' + params[k]}).join('&')"`

which would give you
**'userId[]=1,2&empId=2&advance=hello'**
I think you need this(guessing that you made a typo error)

Comment: If you want to some other output, let me know.

Comment: it is printing userId[]=1,2&empId=2&advance=hello
but i need userId[]=1&userId[]=2&empId=2&advance=hello